# How can I get the distance of the laser pointer from the target(middle) ,given that the target point center is (x=0,z=0) using opencv (JAVA)?

Tags: java, opencv

The given image here is a target point. If we assume that the middle point coordinate is (x=0, Z=0), then how can I measure the distance of the laser point from the target center point. I need to use OpenCV java. I am totally new to this. It will be really helpful if I get the technique!
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZO5q.png

Comment: work through the opencv tutorials (docs.opencv.org), pick/skip whatever you feel like. you'll need `cvtColor` and `inRange` (to get a binary mask describing the dot), `moments` (for the center of mass). if you want a proper answer, I'm gonna need a representative real-world picture. the picture you showed is too clean and trivial to work with, and I'm sure questions would follow that point out some flaw when using a real-world picture.

Comment: Actually, it's a part of a simulation. The real image is the same as this. The task is that I need to use a laser that is implemented in a robot to hit the middle of the target point. So, I want to figure out the distance to calibrate my robot's position to hit the target properly. The X and Z point values are needed.

Comment: And also the robot has the functionality to take snapshots!

Comment: I gave you specific functions to use. you can figure it out if you try.